# How do the react server display?

Tags: reactjs

The React Server is showing a Blank page, Even i am printing "HelloWorld".

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I am expecting a hello world in the react server.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console of the developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your index.js with

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
      <App />
    );
```